# Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 touch stops responding while holding

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung, tablet, touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

The tablet works fine with "normal" use (internet browsing, taking pictures, recording video, using youtube, playing movies, writing texts, etc) but whenever I use it to play a game that requires me to hold a button down for a period of time (And occasionally pressing other buttons at the same time), it lets me hold it but then just stops responding to touch until I lift my finger up and place it back down again. The buttons I'm talking are of course touch buttons of the game.

I went ahead and activated debugging options to see screen touches and coordinates, and it's clear that when this error happens the screen is not registering touches.

At first I thought it was a hardware issue, but the I found other people having the same problem.

This happens not in one game but in all the games I tested which require this kind of action (like league of evil)

Any hint would be appreciated.

Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 SM T230
Android 4.4.2